# Line in the middle of screen

Tags: screen, sony-ericsson-xperia-mini

It showed a few months ago, before I upgraded to ICS. It changes its color depending on wallpaper.

Anyone know how to fix it or what caused it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it appear during boot proccess or only after the Launcher is running?

Comment: what year is that model?

Comment: On my device, that line is smaller. Service said "return for replacement, it's a cold soldering" (i.e. hardware problem). Here it appears right away when the screen is switched on (even on boot) -- but goes away if I leave the device half an hour with screen turned on. Not sure if you's is the same issue, but thought I share it in a comment.

Comment: @Izzy, there's two model variants of mini, the 2010 model and 2011 model, am trying to ascertain which is it, if its 2010 model, ICS is incompatible with it.

Comment: @ruda.almeida It's there during boot process.

Comment: @t0mm13b I don't know. The model name is SK17i. But whatever it is, ICS is not causing the problem, I mentioned it started before the upgrade.

Comment: OP: you're implying it started before ICS right? So its being there since Gingerbread right? As for SK17i, that's defo 2011 model! Hummm... was your handset dropped at any stage? Was it exposed to water/moisture?

Comment: @t0mm13b Yes, it's been there since Gingerbread. It's really preserved, never fell down, without a single scratch. Also never been in water.

Comment: Right, think its hardware problem, a loose connection somewhere ... is it still under warranty?

Answer (score 1):

That is a *Hardware* problem and can be solved only by taking your phone to a Service Center.